# jQuery get sibling using next() returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you use jQuery's `next()` method to get the contents of an element's sibling? I am trying to get text associated with a google search result. To this end, I stored links in a variable with `$('h3.r a')`. Next I added a click handler, which would trigger the code that grabs the page description underneath the link. I expected `$(this).next().html()` to get contents of the next sibling in the same manner `$(this).html()` worked. Unfortunately, I was mistaken. Here is the jQuery, any help is really valued

```
links.click(function() {
    var nextElement = $(this).next()
    console.log(nextElement.html()) //why doesn't this get contents?

    var d = $(this).nextElementSibling
    console.log(d)
})
```

EDIT:  so I checked the console and when I logged `$(this)` I got

```
{  
   "0":{  
      "jQuery311027308429302958161":{  
         "events":{  
            "click":[  
               {  
                  "type":"click",
                  "origType":"click",
                  "data":null,
                  "guid":1,
                  "namespace":""
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   },
   "length":1
}
```

When I logged `$(this).next()`

```
{  
   "length":0,
   "prevObject":{  
      "0":{  
         "jQuery311027308429302958161":{  
            "events":{  
               "click":[  
                  {  
                     "type":"click",
                     "origType":"click",
                     "data":null,
                     "guid":1,
                     "namespace":""
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      },
      "length":1
   }
}
```

Comment: `console.log` the `nextElement` and see what it selects!

Comment: `.nextElementSibling` is not a jQuery method. Use `this.nextSibling`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `this.nextSibling` to select next `#text` node, `.textContent` to select text of node.